# Regex for Vehicle registration number

Tags: javascript, java

I want a regular expression for identifying Vehicles' registration number. A valid registration number must be contain 10 characters or digits but no special characters or whitespaces. For example `KA01AB1234` is a valid registration number whereas `KA01AB 234` is not.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: KA01AB1234- This is the format of input.

Comment: I need a regular expression. I tried some but it willnot eliminate white spaces

Comment: Well, please: a) include what you tried in the question, and b) java or javascript?

Comment: what regex did you try?

Comment: ^[A-Z]{2}\s[0-9]{2}\s[A-Z]{2}\s[0-9]{4}$

Comment: `/^\w{10}$/` should to the trick for "*10 input ie, alphabet characters or digits*".

Comment: But a regex cannot validate the check digit.

Comment: You can use this: inputStr.matches("^\\p{Upper}{2}\\p{Digit}{2}\\p{Upper}{2}\\p{Digit}{4}$");

Answer (score 2):

What about it:

```
Pattern.compile("^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}$")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}$
```

Comment: But another problem is how can we alert while key press of special character or white space. Now it  will alert only after entering 10 characters.

Comment: function alphanumeric(inputtxt)  
{   
var letters = /[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}$/;  
if(inputtxt.value.match(letters))  
{  
alert('Your registration number have accepted : you can try another');  
document.form1.text1.focus();  
return true;  
}  
else  
{  
alert('Please input in correct format');  
return false;  
}  
}

Comment: Great if it is working. I don't know why couple of people thought that answer is useless.

Comment: @Adeel because there's no explanation whatsoever, it's just a pattern